# Can I dynamically set a parameter for c++ node?

Tags: rosparam, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have c++ node running, I am wondering can I change value of a parameter(define value in launch file) dynamically in that node(which means take effect without relaunch the launch file)?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56024/can-i-dynamically-set-a-parameter-for-c++-node?/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can change the parameter on the parameter server anytime you want, but unless your node checks for changes, it won't know about it. For values that you expect to change during execution, [dynamic_reconfigure](http://ros.org/wiki/dynamic_reconfigure) is a better option.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-22**:
Also, you can call getParamCached() anytime a new value might be worth using. Don't use getParam() in that case, it would hammer the parameter server too hard.